# Remove First Character and Comma Delimiter from header line csv using Apache-NiFi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I'm newbie in Apache-Nifi topic.

I have a csv with value :

```
id | title | value
a  | Mr    | 391
b  | Mrs   | 392
```

I use replaceText processor for ensure the header line with `"#"` as replace value and replacement strategy : `Prepend` and Evaluation Mode : `Entire Text`.
Then I use routetext to get the headerline with configuration : Grouping Regular Expression : `(.*?),.*` and new property named `header line` with value `#`.

The result from those process is : "#id,title,value

I want to remove `#` and `,` from that result. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use another ReplaceText processor with a pattern of something like (#|,) and an empty replacement value.